# the limit when n goes to infinity in recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

in this equation I don't know how to calculate the limit of $nP(n)$

$$P(n)=P(n-1)\bigg(1-\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg)P(n-1)\bigg)$$
$$P(0)=1$$

I thought of just expand until I catch some co-relation but I failed.

Comment: Is there a value for a starting term? Like $P(0)$ or $P(1)$?

Comment: I modified the question sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I claim that $\lim_{n\to\infty} nP(n) = 2$.

Define $R(n)=1/P(n)$, so that $R(0)=1$ and the recursive relation can be written (after some rearrangement) in the form
$$
R(n)=R(n-1) + \frac12 + \frac1{4R(n-1)-2}.
$$
From this one can easily show that $R(n)\ge R(n-1) + \frac12$ and hence $R(n) \ge 1+\frac n2$ for all $n$, and then that
$$
R(n) \le R(n-1) + \frac12 + \frac1{2n+2},
$$
for all $n$, which implies that
$$
R(n) \le 1 + \frac n2 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{2k+2} = \frac n2+O(\log n).
$$
Together these inequalities show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} R(n)/n = \frac12$, and so $\lim_{n\to\infty} nP(n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n/R(n) = 2$.

Comment: Hat tip to Pietro Majer for the comments on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298328/how-to-find-the-best-convergence-rate-of-a-dynamical-system-x-n1-gx-n), which taught me how to find this solution!